# A matrix in $SL(2)$ has it's supremum norm and infimum fulfilled by orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am having trouble proving the next statement:

If $B\in SL(2)$ and $||B||\neq 1$, for $||B||:= \underset{x\neq 0}{\sup}\big\{\frac{||B(x)||}{||x||} \big\} $, where $||\cdot||$ is the euclidian norm, then there exist $u$ and $v$ unit vectors, such that they are orthogonal, $B(u)$ and $B(v)$ are orthogonal, and $$||B(u)|| = ||B|| $$ $$||B(v)|| = \inf_{x\neq 0} \big\{\frac{||B(x)||}{||x||}\big\} $$

The part of showing the vectors that fulfill the $\sup$ and $\inf$ is not hard, because the euclidian norm is continuous and $$\sup_{x\neq 0}\big\{\frac{||B(x)||}{||x||}\big\} = \sup_{||x||=1 }\{||B(x)||\}\qquad  \inf_{x\neq 0}\big\{\frac{||B(x)||}{||x||}\big\} = \inf_{||x||=1 }\{||B(x)||\}$$

Using that $\mathbb{S}^1\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is compact there exist $u$ and $v$ in $\mathbb{S}^1$ that are the maximum and infimum of the function $||A(\_)||$.

What I am stuck at is showing that they must be orthogonal. I am also aware that I haven't used the hypothesis $||B||= 1$ so far, and I can't think of how to use it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Choose first $v \in R^{2}$ fixed such that $\| B(v) \| = \inf_{\| x \| = 1} \| B(x) \|$ and $\| v \| = 1$. Now, let $u \in R^{2}$ be orthogonal to $v$ and of unit length (there exist precisely two of these $u$). Then any $x \in R^{2}$ is of the form $x = c_{1} u + c_{2} v$ ($\{u,v\}$ forms a basis). Then $\| B(x) \| = \| c_{1} B(u) + c_{2} B(v) \| \leq | c_{1} | \| B(u) \| + | c_{2} | \| B(v) \|$ and if we assume that $x$ is a unit vector, taking the supremum over both sides gives that $x = u$.

Comment: At the end I think you mean: $$\|B(x)\|=\|c_1B(u)+c_2B(v)\|\leq |c_1|\|B(u)\|+|c_2|\|B(v)\|\leq (|c_1|+|c_2|)\|B(u)\|$$

I don't see why the equality should hold, and I also don't see taking $\|x\|=1$ implies that $\|B(x)\|\leq \|B(u)\|$, since taking $c_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=c_2$ gives as best $\|B(x)\|\leq \sqrt{2}\,\|B(u)\|$

Comment: You are right about your first comment. I changed it (incorrectly), my mistake and I fixed it. If $x = c_{1} u + c_{2} v$, then $x$ is a unit vector if and only if $c_{1}^{2} + c_{2}^{2} = 1$. It is known that $\| B(v) \| \leq \| B(u) \|$ and therefore the maximum at the right hand side is attained at $c_{1} = 1$, $c_{2} = 0$. This gives that $\| B(x) \| \leq \| B(u) \|$ for all $x \in R^{2}$ and thus is $\| B(u) \|$ an upper bound of $\| B(x) \|$ that is attained at $x = u$, i.e. $\| B \| = \| B(u) \|$.